# Hypothesis test for variance in r?

Tags: r, mean, variance

I’m trying to do a hypothesis test of whether the variability of PM2.5 concentration is lower when it’s raining (when rain=0mm and when rain>0mm).

I’m assuming you don’t use the usual `t.test` function.

I’m not sure what function to use,  thinking `var.test` function?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's correct. Use `var.test` to test for equality of _variances_, or a hypothesized ratio (the default being 1). A `t.test` is not appropriate as it is a test of _means_, or as before, a hypothesized difference (the default being 0). Why `var.test` isn't called `F.test` is anyone's guess.

Comment: Can you describe your data better? Which variables, how many observations, one obs site or multiple ... maybe you should go for joint modeling of mean and variance, then look into R package `gamlss`